# Finding a strange Javascript function 'window.ueLogError' in a PhantomJS error message

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm working on a project that involves retrieving multiple websites with PhantomJS and when I try to load Amazon.com, PhantomJS crashes while trying to evaluate this function with the error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.ueLogError')
```

The weird thing is that I can't seem to find any documentation or explanation of any kind for `window.ueLogError`.  A google search gives a handful of websites with scripts that contain it, but it doesn't seem to be a part of any documentation I can find.  Does anyone know anything about `ueLogError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window` object is the global sink in the browser. Every variable that you define globally (e.g. jQuery's `$`) is a property in `window`. `ueLogError` is not some kind of standardized JavaScript function. It is most likely some function for an advertisement script.

Not all resources that a page requests as part of the page load are actually successfully loaded. Some requests fail due to SSL problems. Some requests fail, because the user agent string is not supported. Some requests fail because of unknown reasons.

You can register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)) to see whether there are errors. Usually you will find that some JavaScript file wasn't loaded which would have contained `ueLogError` which another script depends on.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  I am fairly new to handling exceptions in an asynchronous environment like Javascript--what I would like to be able to do is accept that the error occurred and continue executing the phantomjs script (its primary goal is to gather resource timing data, a few JS errors on a large complex page aren't a major concern)  Is there a way to do that in the context of the examples you linked?  Right now execution hangs after the page.onError() function is done.  Thanks again.

Comment: Normally, PhantomJS will execute further code, but it may happen that this error causes some functionality of the page to be broken in which case you would have to solve that first. Did you see that some resources aren't being loaded? Have you tried another version of PhantomJS (v1.9.7/v1.9.8/v2.0.0)?

Comment: Apparent it tried to load

http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/misc/untranslatable-image-id.jpg

Not sure what's generating those URLs.  Also, I'm using a patched version of 1.9.0 I modified to get correct timing data.  Should I use a newer version to potentially solve issues like this?  Thanks.